# Check if a remote image is hotlink-protected

Tags: php, javascript, hotlinking

I would like to check if a remote image is hotlink-protected, or not.

- If the image is not protected against hotlinking, I would like to display the image. (Don't worry, I will add a visible hyperlink to the source, and I will give the legitimate owner the possibility to remove the image.)
- If the image is protected, I would do nothing.

Is it possible (with PHP and/or Javascript) to make the distinction between hotlink-protected images and 'hotlinkable' images?

Comment: just because its not protect does not give you the right to show it on your web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do this from PHP. When you want to hotlink the file, create an HTTP connection and set the Referer header in the request to your site. If you get a 200 response with the image data, it is not hotlink protected. If you get a 301 forwarding response it is hotlink protected.

Comment: This catches some cases, but not all. It only works if the hotlink protection works with redirects but for sites that just deliver another image through a script with a 200 OK response, you can not detect the difference without knowing how the image should look like.

Comment: Actually you can even catch this. Request the image once with your website as the referrer and then again with their website as the referrer. Compare the two.

Comment: How can I do that with PHP?

Comment: You're going to want to use PHP cURL. See an example here http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-http-referer/.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easiest to do something like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.png" onerror="alert('Image not found or protected');" />
```

It is possible to find out, of course, but that would require making an HTTP request, which can be expensive - especially if the remote host is slow or under load.

Comment: Accepted the first reply as my answer, but this is a bright and simple way I didn't even think of in the first place. It seems to work, thank you.
Any idea which solutions is best in terms of speed? This or cURL?

Comment: This one's "better", because it only involves getting the image once, and if it works then the image data is loaded directly. If you do use cURL, make sure you send a `HEAD` request (not `GET`) so that you don't download the image data on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do that in Ruby

```rb
class CheckImageHotlinkStatus
  require 'net/http'
  require 'uri'
  def self.call(image_url)
    uri = URI(image_url)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    req['Referer'] = 'http://your-site-here.com'
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
      http.request(req)
    end
    # Net::HTTPForbidden ...download & embed
    # Net::HTTPOK ...fine to hotlink
    # ...everything else 
    puts response.class
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily detect this per-URL with client-side JavaScript, but you can circumvent hotlinking protections entirely with [hotlink.js](https://eligrey.com/demos/hotlink.js/).